# cannot connect to self-hosted gRPC Windows service

Tags: c#-3.0, grpc

I published my first gRPC Windows service on to a test server.  *Please excuse my clulessness*.

Long story short:
When I tried to connect to it w/ a client, I am getting the error below:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. SocketException: No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it.

Here's my appsettins.json on Kestrel:

```
"HttpsInlineCertStore": {
  "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
  "Certificate": {
    "Subject": "CN=<secret>",
    "Store": "My",
    "Location": "LocalMachine",
    "AllowInvalid": "true"
  }
}
```

On my client, I have this:

```
readonly static GrpcChannel channel =
  GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://full server name and domain:5001");
```

Question:
I keep seeing port 5000 being opened, but no 5001.  Why?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
By default http is on 5000.  Here's [MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1)...search Endpoint Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the proper environment name (aspnetcore_environment) is set, so the configuration of the Kestrel in the specific appsettings..json is loaded.

Andrew Luck has an [article](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/) on how to set the environment variables.

Also, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you can find the different options you can set for the Kestrel.  Search for *Replace the default certificate from configuration* will lead you to the section.